# UWP location to hold local user permissions?

Tags: security, uwp, credentials, user-permissions

Im writing a application where I can have multiple users login and store their password in windows credentials. I currently can successfully validate the user's login. My question is where is the proper place to store the permissions(ex access to a certain page). I have several databases but I don't think that's secure. Possibly encrypt the data in the table. Or maybe in the local settings

Comment: A good place is using the windows credential manager

Answer (score 3):

You should use the [PasswordVault](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.Security.Credentials.PasswordVault) class in a UWP app for storing user credentials so the app can validate silently to your cloud service later.  [Here are details](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/security/credential-locker) on how to use the API.

for non-password, non-sensitive data, you can store it in LocalStorage or RoamingStorage but that is not secure.  The only secure location to store data is on your service.  Look to use something cloud-based like Azure Mobile apps to store that kind of info.

Comment: The PasswordVault is only for storing passwords. I am looking to store data about the user like the what they can do within the app.

Comment: I added some more details.